# java regex matching Arabic words around a key word that may occur twice in a short distance

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match two words or less before and after a certain key word using regex. The text is in Arabic so I used \S+ in the expression below in a java code to match Arabic characters.

I encountered a case when the key word occurred twice in the same string with a distance less than or equals two words.

So how could I edit this expression to handle such a special case.

Arabic Example:
input text: `اذا كان هذا مثال ودليل اذا هذا مثال اخر`

regex: `((\S+\s*){0,2})\bهذا\b\s*((\S+\s*){0,2})`
need to extract group 1 & 3.

predicted output:

1. اذا كان - مثال ودليل
2. **ودليل اذا** - مثال اخر

actual output:

1. اذا كان - مثال ودليل
2. **اذا** - مثال اخر

Example in English for illustartion:

translated text: if this is an example this is another one

regex: `((\S+\s*){0,2})\bis\b\s*((\S+\s*){0,2})`
need to extract group 1 & 3.

predicted output:

1. if this - an example
2. **example this** - another one

actual output:

1. it this - an example
2. **this** - another one

Example on Rubular: http://www.rubular.com/r/G5ctauWdYH

Comment: You need to use lookaheads or lookbehinds inorder to do overlapping of matches.

Comment: As the problem does not seem to be arabic-specific, I think it would be clearer (and shorter) not mentionning it at all

Comment: @Dici: I mentioned that to justify using \S instead of \w+ because \w+ couldnt match arabic chars

Comment: @Daisy oh right, thanks for the precision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, uses a lookahead for overlapps.
Note that the ideal is to use a variable length lookbehind as well, **but** Java doesn't support it.

```
 # "((?:(?!\\bis\\b)\\S+\\s*){0,2})\\bis\\b\\s*(?=((?:(?!\\bis\\b)\\S+\\s*){0,2}))"

 (                             # (1 start), 0-2 words before
      (?:
           (?! \b is \b )                # But, not the target word
           \S+ \s* 
      ){0,2}
 )                             # (1 end)
 \b is \b \s* 
 (?=                           # Lookahead, Overlap so next search starts here.
      (                             # (2 start), 0-2 words after
           (?:
                (?! \b is \b )                # But, not the target word
                \S+ \s* 
           ){0,2}
      )                             # (2 end)
 )
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 11 ) 
if this is   
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 0 , len 8 ) 
if this   
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 11 , len 11 ) 
an example   

---------------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 14 , len 16 ) 
example this is   
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 14 , len 13 ) 
example this   
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 30 , len 13 ) 
another one
```